# JPA Criteria API join query One To Many with condition

Tags: java, json, hibernate-criteria, criteria-api, criteriaquery

I have 2 Table

1. Enterprise

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Alex |

2. Product

| ID | Name | Status | EnterpriseId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | Iphone12 | ACTIVE | 1 |
| 8 | Iphone11 | ACTIVE | 1 |
| 6 | Iphone13 | DISABLE | 1 |

The relationship is one to many (one Enterprise having many Product). I want to get an `Enterprise` with all their `Product` with a condition is `Status` of this `Product` is `ACTIVE`

How can I get the result in json is

```
  {
"id": "1",
"name": "Alex",
"products": [
  {
    "id": "7",
    "name": "Iphone12",      
  },
  {
    "id": "8",
    "name": "Iphone11",
  }
 ]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that your entities model is:

```
@Entity
class Enterprise {
   ...
   @OneToMany
   List<Product> products;
}

@Entity
class Product {
   ...

   String status;
}
```

The following criteria should work:

```
CriteriaQuery<Enterprise> criteria = builder.createQuery(Enterprise.class);
Root<Author> root = criteria.from( Enterprise.class );
Join<Object, Object> productsJoin = root.join( "products" );
criteria.where( builder.equal( productsJoin.get("status"), "ACTIVE" ) );
List<Enterprise> result = session.createCriteria(criteria).getResultList();
```

It's the same as the HQL query:

```
from Enterprise e join e.products p
where p.status = 'ACTIVE'
```

If you want to load the association eagerly you can replace `root.join` with `root.fetch`:

```
CriteriaQuery<Enterprise> criteria = builder.createQuery(Enterprise.class);
Root<Author> root = criteria.from( Enterprise.class );
Join<Object, Object> productsJoin = (Join<Object, Object>)root.fetch( "products" );
criteria.where( builder.equal( productsJoin.get("status"), "ACTIVE" ) );
List<Enterprise> result = session.createCriteria(criteria).getResultList();
```

Here's the equivalent HQL query:

```
from Enterprise e join fetch e.products p
where p.status = 'ACTIVE'
```

You can find more examples in [this article](https://thorben-janssen.com/hibernate-tip-left-join-fetch-join-criteriaquery/) or in [the Hibernate ORM documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.6/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#criteria).